# DNN 9 restrict a logged in user to a single session at any one time

Tags: dotnetnuke

I want to be able to make it so a registered user can only be logged into the DNN site from one device/browser at any one time.

I understand that the DNN core doesn't support sessions but does have a a users online table which is checked by the scheduler, however i have been unable to find anything available to use this method.

The main purpose is to stop a paid user from sharing their login details with multiple people and thereby diluting the potential revenue to the site. I would think this was not a unique use case and someone must have dealt with this previously.

Open to any and all ideas including commercial modules.

Comment: I've created a new module to restrict a user to a single login based on IP. Still beta, but you can download it temporarily from [here](http://modules.vdwwd.eu/portals/1022/VDWWD_SingleLogin_01.00.00_UnzipMe_BPNZ.zip) if you want to test it (will leave it for a week or so to download). I have modules published in the [DNN Store](http://store.dnnsoftware.com/vendor-profile/vdwwd), should you question the legitimacy of my module.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you could create a custom login module, and reject logins from a user who appear as active in the UsersOnline table.

I haven't looked around to see what methods are available, but the old usersonline module should provide some hints.

Comment: I've spend the last couple of hour trying to enable the Users Online functionality in DNN 9. Including installing the UsersOnline Module itself. Prior to 9 you could enable the functionality in the Host Settings, but that has been removed ([source](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/enable-users-online-dnn-91)). However just adding the host setitng manually does not seem to work.